# react native init: ReferenceError: [BABEL] Unknown option: Unknown option: base.optional

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I'm getting the following error upon running `react-native init testNative`

```
ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/bundle/bundle.js: Unknown option: base.optional
    at Logger.error (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:41:11)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:289:18)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:486:10)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:211:75)
    at new File (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:129:22)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:48:16)
    at Object.transformFileSync (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/node.js:118:10)
    at compile (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:100:20)
    at loader (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:128:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/m/git/testNative/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
```

I've tried the advice in the following posts (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5, https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/132, https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/129, [React 0.14 error: Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] .../node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js!/.../main.jsx: Unknown option: base.stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33630696/react-0-14-error-module-build-failed-referenceerror-babel-node-modules)), but with no avail.

My current hypothesis is that because I don't have a .babelrc file anywhere on my system, it's falling back to "base.optional." At least adding a .babelrc file to my project folder is the only thing that yielded a different outcome (downgrading node, babel, or react-native did nothing). So, if this is the solution, does anyone know what my .babelrc file should include for a react-native project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the `.babelrc` files that you can use with your RN project.
Note that RN works fine with no `.babelrc` file in your project (it falls back to `node_modules/react-native/.babelrc` file.

```
{
  "retainLines": true,
  "compact": true,
  "comments": false,
  "plugins": [],
  "presets": ["stage-0", "react", "react-native"],
  "sourceMaps": false,
}
```

You also need to add these line to your `package.json` file and install the dev-dependencies : `npm i --save-dev <package-name>`

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.4.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13"
}
```